# Optimising a complex SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, symfony, doctrine

I have the following query in use on my Symfony2 site, for locating the nearest latitude and longitude pairs to a given point on the map. There is a table 'latlong' which stores these pairs, as well as a table 'fos_user_user' which stores the users, and a 'usermeta' table which stores data about these users (this is a hangover from when we moved all the data over from wordpress). The problem is that it runs very slowly - it used to be reasonably quick when we ran a very simlar query on the old WordPress site. Does anyone have any ideas of how to optimise it?

```
SELECT 
  latlong.user AS id, 
  fos_user_user.username AS username, 
  latlong.lat AS lat, 
  latlong.lng AS lng, 
  fos_user_user.email_canonical AS email, 
  firstname.VALUE AS firstname, 
  lastname.VALUE AS lastname, 
  address1.VALUE AS address1, 
  address2.VALUE AS address2, 
  address3.VALUE AS address3, 
  postcode.VALUE AS postcode, 
  image.VALUE AS image, 
  (
    3959 * ACOS(
      COS(
        RADIANS('51.4424728')
      ) * COS(
        RADIANS(lat)
      ) * COS(
        RADIANS(lng) - RADIANS('7.2586558')
      ) + SIN(
        RADIANS('51.4424728')
      ) * SIN(
        RADIANS(lat)
      )
    )
  ) AS distance 
FROM 
  latlong 
  JOIN fos_user_user ON latlong.user = fos_user_user.id 
  LEFT JOIN usermeta AS firstname ON firstname.user_id = latlong.user 
  AND firstname.field_id = '15' 
  LEFT JOIN usermeta AS lastname ON lastname.user_id = latlong.user 
  AND lastname.field_id = '16' 
  LEFT JOIN usermeta AS image ON image.user_id = latlong.user 
  AND image.field_id = '11' 
  LEFT JOIN usermeta AS address1 ON address1.user_id = latlong.user 
  AND address1.field_id = '2' 
  LEFT JOIN usermeta AS address2 ON address1.user_id = latlong.user 
  AND address1.field_id = '3' 
  LEFT JOIN usermeta AS address3 ON address1.user_id = latlong.user 
  AND address1.field_id = '4' 
  LEFT JOIN usermeta AS postcode ON postcode.user_id = latlong.user 
  AND postcode.field_id = '5' 
  LEFT JOIN usermeta AS public ON public.user_id = latlong.user 
  AND public.field_id = '10' 
WHERE 
  public.value = 'YES' 
HAVING 
  distance < 25 
ORDER BY 
  distance ASC 
LIMIT 
  0, 5
```

Comment: Table structure? `Explain`?

Comment: Horrible db design. You know WHERE public.value = 'YES' makes that last LEFT JOIN to execute as an inner join? (Move condition to ON clause to execute as left join.) HAVING is typically for aggregate functions, move that condition to WHERE instead. (MySQL extension to allow column alisases there...)

Comment: You need something stronger. With this condition mysql have to compute distances to all users (with all this joins).

Comment: thanks for your comments, there are 3 tables involved

fos_user_user (the users table),
usermeta (the meta values table with 3 columns, user_id, field_id and value - essentially the values table in the EAV),
latlong -  this has latitude and longitude pairs and a user ID

@jarlh - could you give an example of how i would combine the public.value = 10 condition with the ON clause?